# SharePoint BreadCrumb Question

Tags: 2013, site-settings, breadcrumb

I have a SharePoint URL for one site as: `http://xyz/controls/engineering/test`

Where test is the subsite of engineering, whose breadcrumb is set as:

> xyz> controls> engineering> sites> test

I created another subsite under Engineering: `http://xyz/controls/engineering/test2`

Now breadcrumb is published as:

> xyz> controls> engineering> test2

I am not sure why sites are visible at first site and it isn't in another one?

Sites breadcrumb is basically referencing it parent site which is engineering?

Comment: What kind of template being used for engineering, also for test& test2

Comment: BI Template is used.

Comment: Could you include some screen shots?

Answer (score 0):

You did not state a SharePoint version, but it sounds like you are using 2010, or a site created from a 2010 template. By design, 2010 eliminates the "middle" tiers to insure that the entire crumb trail is to too long for the page. I'm not sure what the rules are for determining "too long".

I have some screen captures of how 2007, 2010 and 2013 use crumb trails, and some work arounds here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-restoring-2010-navigate.html and here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/11/add-crumb-trail-to-sharepoint-2013.html